# C prepending node to a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to prepend an element to a linked list made up of value and next, but the original list is always being returned, any thoughts?

Note: I cannot change the signature.

```
intlist* intlist_prepend(intlist* xs, int val) 
{
    intlist* ys = (intlist*)malloc(sizeof(intlist));
    ys->val = val;
    ys->next = xs;
    return ys;
}
```

Here is my test case:

```
intlist* prepend = malloc(sizeof(intlist*));
    prepend->val = 5;
    prepend->next = NULL;

    printf("\n*** testing intlist_prepend\n\n");
    printf("expecting 6 5: ");
    intlist_prepend(prepend, 6);
    intlist_show(prepend);
    printf("\nexpecting 7 6 5: ");
    intlist_prepend(prepend, 7);
    intlist_show(prepend);
```

But 5 is only being returned.

Comment: How do you know the original list is always being returned?

Comment: @immibis I've added my test case to the post

Comment: Do you call like `xs = intlist_prepend(xs, value);` ?

Comment: You do not need to cast `malloc`

Comment: You threw away the value returned.

Comment: @JerseyFonseca Your test program ignores the value returned and prints the original list, how do you know what was returned?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY This worked, thank you. But this was not the case in my append test functions:

my append function has the type: intlist* intlist_append(intlist* xs, int val) 

so why don't I have to do this for append?

Comment: I don't get you.

Comment: @JerseyFonseca I think you can work out the answer yourself, if you understand pointers.

Comment: @JerseyFonseca The original `xs` is returned in `intlist_append`, right? That is, you're always returning the head of the list. An append operation can never replace the head of the list because it always adds an item at the end of the list, meaning the item added is never returned (an exception is an empty/NULL list). A prepend operation replaces the head of the list because it always adds an item at the beginning, meaning the item added is always returned. Think about it for a moment, and you'll understand why you should be able to realize this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

When you are prepending, you need to update the head of the list. So the return value from the `intlist_prepend()` becomes the new head.

```
intlist* prepend = malloc(sizeof(intlist*));
prepend->val = 5;
prepend->next = NULL;

printf("\n*** testing intlist_prepend\n\n");
printf("expecting 6 5: ");
prepend = intlist_prepend(prepend, 6);
intlist_show(prepend);
printf("\nexpecting 7 6 5: ");
prepend = intlist_prepend(prepend, 7);
intlist_show(prepend);
```

Comment: Your `malloc` is perfectly fine, but using the dereferenced variable itself will always insure proper allocation, e.g. `intlist *prepend = malloc (sizeof *prepend);` Additionally, the `'*'` in pointer declarations should be attached to the *variable* and not the *type* to insure there is no confusion, e.g. `int* a, b, c;` (`b` & `c` are certainly not integer pointers...) `int *a, b, c;` makes that clearer.

Comment: Good points and I completely agree. I partly blame it on my copy/paste which I know is not a good reason.

Comment: Yep, no worries, I figured as much and gave you the vote. I always try to remember when answering questions, that I step into the role of teacher and try and make sure to address all the issues I see (not always successful at catching them all, but we try...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Question about your statement `intlist *prepend = malloc (sizeof *prepend); // Must this be sizeof prepend?` I ask this because sizeof prepend will return the number of bytes required to store the pointer variable 'prepend': Isnt that what we require here?

Comment: No, recall you declared `prepend` as a pointer. You want to allocate adequate space for whatever the pointer points to, rather than just `sizeof (a pointer)`, so you dereference `prepend` to get the `sizeof (the object)`. (e.g. `int *a;`, `sizeof a;` is `sizeof (a pointer to int)`, `sizeof *a;` is `sizeof (an int)`.